# Correct Data Protection Declaration

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have an app that is to be released onto the Microsoft Store. Because it uses the restricted Capability `AppDiagnostics`, I am required to provide a URL to a Data Protection URL. But my app does not have any Internet capabilities, so as far as I know I am not even able to receive any data, right? So what should I provide? A simple statement that no data is received? Or is this a special case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your app package manifest source file (Package.appxmanifest),check the xmlns:rescap XML namespace and the rescap prefix , there should be some configuration code:

```xml
    <Package
        ...
        xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
        IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
    ...
    <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="AppDiagnostics"/>
    </Capabilities>
    </Package>
```

**[Restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities)**:Intended for very specific scenarios and needed
providing info during the app submission process in order to be approved to publish the app to the Microsoft Store.

**AppDiagnostics**(a kind of restricted capabilities):The appDiagnostics capability allows an app to get diagnostic information, (such as package information, memory usage, and account name) for any other running UWP app. The information returned includes the *domain/machine account name*(These information belong to the users' Personal Information) under which the app is running.

With this capability, your app need to provide the information for app submission approval and provide the [privacy policy URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/enter-app-properties#privacy-policy-url) for your user to get the access of collecting the private information in the Dev center dashboard.So if you don't need this restricted capability, remove the config in xml.